# How to move the XML elements as per conditions

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a XML like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLECTION>
<AddedBOMs NAME="AddedBOMs" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<BOMHeader>
    <Number>One</Number>
    <StartEffectivity>One 00:00:00</StartEffectivity>
    <EndEffectivity>One 00:00:00</EndEffectivity>
</BOMHeader>
</AddedBOMs>
<ChangedBOMs NAME="ChangedBOMs" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<BOMHeader>
    <Number>Two</Number>
    <StartEffectivity>Two 00:00:00</StartEffectivity>
    <EndEffectivity>Two 00:00:00</EndEffectivity>
</BOMHeader>
</ChangedBOMs>
<UnchangedBOMs NAME="UnchangedBOMs" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<BOMHeader>
    <Number>Three</Number>
    <StartEffectivity>Three 00:00:00</StartEffectivity>
    <EndEffectivity>Three 00:00:00</EndEffectivity>
</BOMHeader>
</UnchangedBOMs>
<DeletedBOMComponents NAME="DeletedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<BOMComponent>
    <PartNumber>Three</PartNumber>
</BOMComponent>
</DeletedBOMComponents>
<AddedBOMComponents NAME="AddedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<BOMComponent>
    <PartNumber>Two</PartNumber>
</BOMComponent>
</AddedBOMComponents>
<ChangedBOMComponents NAME="ChangedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<BOMComponent>
    <PartNumber>One</PartNumber>
</BOMComponent>
</ChangedBOMComponents>
</COLLECTION>
```

I want to move **StartEffectivity** and **EndEffectivity** from **AddedBOMs/BOMHeader** but it should be linked with the **../../BOMComponent/PartNumber** i.e whichever part number from BOMComponent matches to the Number of BOMHeader it's respective StartEffectivity and EndEffectivity copied inside BOMComponent

expected output:

```
<DeletedBOMComponents NAME="DeletedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<BOMComponent>
    <PartNumber>Three</PartNumber>
    <StartEffectivity>Three 00:00:00</StartEffectivity>
    <EndEffectivity>Three 00:00:00</EndEffectivity>
</BOMComponent>
</DeletedBOMComponents>
<AddedBOMComponents NAME="AddedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<BOMComponent>
    <PartNumber>Two</PartNumber>
    <StartEffectivity>Two 00:00:00</StartEffectivity>
    <EndEffectivity>Two 00:00:00</EndEffectivity>
</BOMComponent>
</AddedBOMComponents>
<ChangedBOMComponents NAME="ChangedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<BOMComponent>
    <PartNumber>One</PartNumber>
    <StartEffectivity>One 00:00:00</StartEffectivity>
    <EndEffectivity>One 00:00:00</EndEffectivity>
</BOMComponent>
</ChangedBOMComponents>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic that needs to be applied here is not at all clear. Assuming you want to copy only "components", while copying nodes from the corresponding `BOMHeader`, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="header" match="BOMHeader" use="Number" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/COLLECTION">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[BOMComponent]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BOMComponent">
    <xsl:variable name="head" select="key('header', PartNumber)" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="PartNumber"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$head/StartEffectivity | $head/EndEffectivity"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me. But my rest of the XML  should be the same. it need not drop.

Comment: One more thing I need to ask is it possible ?? in case of DeletedBOMComponents /BOMComponent The StartEffectivity  need to be null and EndEffectivity will contain the value of StartEffectivity  from BOMHeader

Comment: @eddie If you want to preserve the "header" elements, simply remove the 2nd template. -- WRT to the additional requirement, I have answered this in your other question.